# How to find capitalized word and add a character before that in given sentence using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, capitalization

So I have a string like this:

> var response = "Connecting to server Connection has been successful We found result";

I wanted to insert a ',' before each capitalized word after I find second Capitalized word.

I am doing this:

> var response = "Connecting to server Connection has been successful We found result";
>        var pattern=/[A-Z]/g;
>        document.write(response.replace(pattern,','));

Result:

> ,onnecting to server ,onnection has been successful ,e found result

What I want:

> Connecting to server,Connection has been successful, We found result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace` a space followed by a capital letter with a comma plus that grouping (`$1`).

```
var res2 = response.replace(/( [A-Z])/g, ',$1');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jyzsuxy8/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex and apositive lookahead.

```
String#replace(/ (?=[A-Z])/g, ', ')
```

```js
document.write('Connecting to server Connection has been successful We found result'.replace(/ (?=[A-Z])/g, ', '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "Connecting to server Connection has been successful We found result";

str.replace(/.[A-Z]/g, ',$&');
```

Result: **Connecting to server, Connection has been successful, We found result**

> When a match is found, if you want to include the matched text in the
>   replacement string, you can access it using $&.